# Cannot ping VMware IP address from Android TV

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, adb, vmware

I am new to Android and Network.
I have a system as the following:
I have a Linux VM on Windows computer that has a specific IP address and I will use it to host a website. I can ping the IP address of Windows computer in the VMware, and I can ping IP of the VMware from the Windows computer.
I also have a Linux computer which is connected to the Android TV through ADB. I can ping the IP address of the Windows computer from both the Android TV and Linux computer.
I can also ping the IP addresses of Android TV and Linux computer from both Linux VM and Windows computer.
However, I cannot ping VMware from the Android TV and Linux computer.

I have disabled all the firewalls in order to enable pinging as far as I have searched so far.
I also tried to use bridged connection but in that way, the virtual machine didn't get any IP address.
Could you please recommend me a solution for pinging VMware that runs on Windows computer from the Linux computer?

Thank you.

Comment: How is networking on the Linux VM configured? If the VM is providing services it should be configured to "Bridged Networking".